# Making static methods explicitly reference the class

Tags: python, coding-style, static-methods

Python allows to call a static method not only from a class, but also from an instance:

```
class X:
  @staticmethod
  def f():
    print('f')

x = X()
X.f() 
x.f() # same as above
```

This may be convenient when we only have an instance to work with; after all, who wants to write `x.__class__.f()` instead of `x.f()`.

But I found that many readers of the code (including myself) tend to interpret `x.f()` as if it's an instance method. That is, they assume that whatever is done either uses or changes `x`. In some cases, this even resulted in bugs (where the developer incorrectly interpreted the semantics of `f`).

So I was thinking to adopt a convention where all static methods are called only using the class object. Are there any static analysis tools that would warn me if this convention is violated?

Comment: Since a `@staticmethod` is basically a function, you could always move it outside the class.

Comment: create a new decorator `enforced_staticmethod` that uses `classmethod` and check if the first element is a class or an instance then raise an error. But I would never do that.

Comment: @DietrichEpp True, but I do want it to be in the class, for namespace and clarity purposes.

Comment: @JBernardo Yeah, but that's too heavy-handed. I don't want to create new decorators that developers have to figure out and use correctly. I just want the static analyzer to point out when this convention is violated (so I can choose whether each occurrence is worth fixing).

Comment: @max this is the easiest way to achieve that. Static analyzers in Python don't really work.. I wrote an answer with an implementation

Comment: @Valentin Perrelle: why do you say this has nothing to do with static analysis? Is there a better tag to describe the tools that perform analysis of the source code and warn you about certain situations?

Comment: I missunderstood the question. I wanted to cancel my edit, but couldn't find the way to do it, and the edit have been approved... I thought it was more a matter of coding-style. (there is a tag for that) But it is true that "f is a static method" is a static property that a static analyzer could prove. (Though JBernardo already pointed out that a static analyzer in Python is unlikely to be able to achieve that)

Comment: @Valentin Perrelle Oh no worries, and yeah static analyzers don't seem to handle this. I'll edit it back only if I have any other edits to make.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this amount of static checking is pythonic, but...

```
class enforced_staticmethod(staticmethod):
     def __get__(self, instance, cls):
         if instance is not None:
             raise Exception('Do not call with an instance.')
         return super(enforced_staticmethod, self).__get__(self)


class C:
    @enforced_staticmethod
    def hai(x):
        return x + 1
```

And you can test:

```
>>> C.hai(10)
11
>>> C().hai(10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#52>", line 1, in <module>
    C().hai(10)
  File "<pyshell#48>", line 4, in __get__
    raise Exception('Do not call with an instance.')
Exception: Do not call with an instance.
```

Comment: Hmm now that I think about it, why is this not Pythonic? It doesn't interfere with duck typing. It doesn't prevent any particular language idioms from being used. It just removes very minor syntactic sugar, forcing people to write `X.f()` or `x.__class__.f()` instead of `x.f()` when `f` is a class method. Or is there more to this restriction than I see?

Comment: @max My opinion is that people should be free to choose how to use the tools provided. If you feel better using static methods this way, go on, this will work. BTW, I would write `type(x).f()` instead of `x.__class__.f()` (unless you're using old style classes)